# How do I stop Visual Studio from inserting "object" when I type "new {"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

When editing a C# source file, I type

```
new {
```

Visual Studio auto-corrects it to

```
new object{
```

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can configure which characters being typed commit the current intellisense selection. In Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | IntelliSense.

Remove "{" and ensure committed by the space bar is not checked.

NB. This option is no longer present as of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Awesome, I'm off my bed of nails!

Comment: I tried this but it did not stop either of the problems (auto-completion on space and on {), even after restarting.  Perhaps it's Resharper?

Comment: I don't get this option in Community 2015 version, it just gives me a few checkboxes - Completion Lists and Selected in Completion List

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox and also no longer present in 2015 Enterprise.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue, and the answers above didn't work for me. In my case, it was caused by Resharper, and I addressed it by navigating to **Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Intellisense -> Completing Characters** and adding the opening curly brace character "{" to the "Do not complete on" list for C#.

Answer (score 1):

What are you typing before the `new {`?

I've just tried it and it auto-completes with the object type, so if I type:

```
Button test = new {
```

it becomes:

```
Button test = new Button{
```

But if I type:

```
var test = new {
```

it leaves it alone.

I haven't configured my VS2008 install in any way.

Comment: This happens in the argument list of a method call, for example, in ASP.Net MVC for the object routeValues parameter of Action Link.

Comment: Ah - I'd noticed it there, but didn't connect it with your question. @Richard's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your auto-complete options for ReSharper? I just tried this in a new (empty) class with the default ReSharper settings and couldn't duplicate it. What version of studio/ReSharper are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing the left brace first, then going back and typing new.  VS2008 does this for me (without ReSharper) and, if I remember, this is what I do.  It's less typing than deleting the inserted "object".

Comment: you're right, it's VS not RS. still, can this behavior be overridden?

Comment: If you're going for speed, you can hit `Ctrl`+`Z` to get rid of `object`.