# How do I stop Visual Studio from automatically adding the end-of-comment characters when I start a new comment in a CSS file

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, comments

In Visual Studio 2012, when I want to comment out one or more lines in a CSS file using the `/*` and `*/` characters, VS always automatically adds the closing comment characters `*/` right after I type the starting comment characters. So if I start with this block of code:

```
.appGrid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 120px 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 140px 80px 1fr;
}
```

and I want to comment out the `-ms-grid-rows` line, I type `/*` at the beginning of that line. This is what I want to see:

```
.appGrid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 120px 1fr;
/*    -ms-grid-rows: 140px 80px 1fr;
}
```

Instead, VS adds the `*/` characters as soon as I finish typing the `/*` characters, like this:

```
.appGrid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 120px 1fr;
/**/    -ms-grid-rows: 140px 80px 1fr;
}
```

I then have to manually delete the automatically-added `*/` and re-add it where I actually want it...in this case at the end of the line I'm trying to comment out.

How can I stop VS from automatically adding the `*/` characters? I couldn't find any option to disable this behavior in Tools>Options>TextEditor>CSS.

For reference, I'm using VS2012 Premium.

Comment: What happens when you highlight the entire block of CSS code you want to comment out, and then hit the "comment out the selected lines" button (or CTRL+E, C)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Using the "comment out the selected lines" button works properly

Comment: You can also customize it, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717252/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-from-inserting-object-when-i-type-new .

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tend to use both approaches often, whichever just feels natural at the moment, so it's really annoying that starting comments manually with /* doesn't work only in CSS files. It works fine for me in all other files that use the /* type of comment

Comment: @RandomUs1r Unfortunately there is no option to customize Intellisense like this for CSS files in VS...there isn't even an Intellisense option available under Tools>Options>TextEditor>CSS

Comment: what happens when you uncheck Auto List members?

Comment: @RandomUs1r It still auto-adds the closing comment symbols

Comment: I would cut the css, do your comment, then paste the text in between, probably faster ;)

Comment: In javascript (and typescript) this also happens, but this is caused by web essentials, and it's possible to toggle it off in the Options > Web Essentials > JavaScript > auto-complete multi-line comments. I know it's a bit off-topic here, but this is the only question about this I could find on google.

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid there isn't an option to change this in Visual Studio, at least not one I can see.
I've had the same issue sometimes, and generally use three ways around it:

1. Select the lines to comment out and use the keyboard shortcut: CTRL+K, C
2. Cut the closing */ and paste it at the end of the location
3. Press CTRL+Z to undo the closing */

The first is the best method, but if I've already started typing 2 or 3 are enough to get through the break in flow!

Answer (score 5):

Luckily for c++ there is an option:
Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Complete Multiline Comments

But not for CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio - Tools - Options - Text Editor - C/C++ - General -
Uncheck 'Automatic brace completion'

Comment: Incorrect. This setting neither applies to CSS nor to /* */ comments.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 22 allows you to turn it off for C++ inside language options. As I did not work with CSS, and don't have its tools installed, not sure if it works for CSS.
As I ended up here searching for a c++ solution, I think it is worth to mention.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly avilable in VS.
You can do this by selecting the content first (including multiple rows) and then pressing the short cut **CTRL+K,CTRL+C** command in the editor.

Comment: This is good info, but as you can see, this info was already given by Rich in his answer over a year ago

Comment: @Rich Yeah this is the age-old debate of what to do with answers that say "what you're asking isn't currently possible, but here's the best workaround". You gave good info in your answer, so I upvoted. But I always hesitate to mark answers like these as _the_ answer...I'd rather leave it unmarked to indicate that my problem still exists. Thanks for the input though!